# How to iterate through all textarea tags and add a node after them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not a jquery developer and I'm not much of a javascript developer too. I'm trying a quick hack that makes my life simple. This is the page:
[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. I want to add a `div` of mathjax_preview class after each `textarea` element on the page.
2. The inner.HTML of that div must the text inside the corresponding `textarea`

But it doesn't seem to work.

I've the following javascript code in `js/1.js` and it is being loaded when the page loads:

```
var preview_number = 0;
$("textarea").each(function() { 
    var d = $(this).next();
    if (!d.hasClass("mathjax_preview")) {
      preview_number++;
      var d = $("<div class='mathjax_preview' " +
         "style='padding: 5px; color: black; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #888;float:left;'" +
         "></div>");
      d.attr("id", "mathjax_preview_" + preview_number);
      d.insertAfter(this);
    } 
    d.text($(this).val());
    MathJax.Hub.Queue([ "Typeset", MathJax.Hub, d.attr("id") ]);
});
```

**EDIT:**

I just inserted following snippet in the beginning of the above file:

```
var preview_number = 0;
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
  alert(elements.length);
```

Its alerting `0`. How come?

Comment: Did you put your code in the `ready` callback or at least at the end of the page?

Comment: @Felix Kling: No! thats what I'm fiddling with. As of now `1.js` is loaded in `head` section. How to do the  `ready` callback you are talking about?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Hello_jQuery (and Terric's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (I've not tested this as it's straight off the top of my head):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var preview_number = 0;

    $("textarea").each(function() { 
        preview_number++;

        var d = document.createElement("div");
        $(d).attr("id", "mathjax_preview_" + preview_number);
        $(d).addClass("mathjax_preview");
        $(d).css("padding", "5px");
        $(d).css("color", "black");
        $(d).css("background", "#eee");
        $(d).css("border", "1px solid #888");
        $(d).css("float", "left");
        $(d).html($(this).val());

        MathJax.Hub.Queue([ "Typeset", MathJax.Hub, $(d).attr("id") ]);

        $(this).append(d);
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, if your snippet is alerting 0 then it means there are no TEXTAREA elements in your DOM.  This could mean that your script is running before your DOM has fully loaded.  Make sure your code is in the $(document).ready() function (as is the snippet above) to ensure your DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Also, to tidy that up I'd suggest putting those CSS attributes into the mathjax_preview class and not inline.

Comment: Two recommendations: Pass an object with all the properties to `.css()` and cache the return value of `$(d)` or use jQuery to create the element `$('<div />', {id: ..., 'class': ..., html: ...})`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `textarea` does not exist. Use `this` instead:

```
d.insertAfter(this);
```

Comment: Sorry! that was a typo. I corrected it but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `textarea` variable defined.

```
d.insertAfter(textarea);
```

I beleive you can use `$(this)` reference.

```
d.insertAfter($(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `textarea` in `d.insertAfter(textarea);`?

It seems to be `d.insertAfter($(this));`.

Answer (score 1):

The alert message is showing you zero because  you have not put your javascript file at the end of page nor you have used ready callback.
To use ready callback add the code as follows

$(document).ready(function() {/*add your javascript code here */});